# How do I set up Anonymous FTP user in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp

I wish to set up a single FTP user which has access to just one directory and its sub-directories.

I got halfway down this road a few months back and now have completely lost my way as to what I have done so far. I have a user already which works via FTP but its allowing access to everything, even the root dir.

The user is called `tmpuser` which shows the following from the `groups` command.

```
tmpuser : tmpuser
```

How do I restrict this user's permissions to only access a single `directory` - in this case the `/tmp` directory.

Using this tutorial http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/05/21/how-to-install-and-configure-ftp-server-with-chroot-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

This is the contents of /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES
#
# Run standalone with IPv6?
# Like the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6 socket
# instead of an IPv4 one. This parameter and the listen parameter are mutually
# exclusive.
#listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

And this is the contents of /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

```
 tmpuser
```

Now when running the following its not running and FTP log in fails

```
root@server:~# service vsftpd restart
stop: Unknown instance:
vsftpd start/running, process 14124
```

Comment: There are very many guides on how to do that online, like for instancethis one http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/05/21/how-to-install-and-configure-ftp-server-with-chroot-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/  Can you tell us what you tried and how you failed? In this case we shall be able to help you.

Comment: Good point, I have run through that now and come unstuck, config, etc updated in my original question.

Comment: That's not a fail: it is just telling you it could not stop the previous instance because it is not running. Then it claims it started the new instance as proc 14124. You can check whether it is still running by means of *sudo service vsftpd status*. If it is not running, there will be a file, /var/log/vsftpd.log, containing details of why it failed. You can go through that, and report here if you get stuck.

Comment: The status is `vsftpd stop/waiting` and the log doesn't have any errors, just client connections.

Comment: The log is empty because it did not even start. Start it by hand, *sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd* and see which error it reports.

Comment: you need to give permission to the user with chmod. and in vsftpd folder crease a cutom user config file and set the directories there. here you go https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd

Comment: @MariusMatutiae starting like that helped, it gave me an error `root@server:~# sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd
500 OOPS: unrecognised variable in config file: allow_writeable_chroot`. I have removed the offending line, but presumably its needed?

Comment: Its started now but tmpuser will not log in.

Comment: Same recipe: start the daemon by hand, try to connect from another pc, see the error messages.

Comment: This is causing issues `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` and with that in place it won't start at all. And now even without that I cannot log in at all via FTP.